# How can I create an empty instance of class in java or how should I initialize it?

Tags: java, initialization

Just like the title I described above.

I'm a little confused about **how to initialize variables** such as an instance of a class or some collections like **ArrayList** or **HashMap**, so I tried something below:

```
private MyObject someObject; // custom class
private ArrayList<String> someArrayList;

// in Constructor Method
this.someObject = null; // is it correct?
```

I made an initialization statement in the Constructor, but I don't know if it is right.
Thanks for your reading and concern.

Comment: the initial value can also be part of the declaration of the field: `private ArrayList<String> someArrayList = null;`, it doesn't need to be in the constructor.

Comment: Fields are null by default (unless they're primitives e.g. int). So assigning null with `= null` doesn't do anything. It's not *incorrect*, it's just redundant.

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - Initializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: well, it also depends on whether you are using keywords like `static` or `final` what you are doing now is redundant, though sometimes IDEs would warn/highlight is as uninitialized if you did not assign a null to a variable and only declared it.

Comment: Collections are usually initialized as empty collections, that way usual operations like modifying or querying its member/size don't have to check if it's not null, though that might depend on the business process, whether, say, someone who doesn't smoke will have their list of preferred cigarette brand as a null or empty list.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting clearer about the initialization right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial property values can be set within a class constructor so when you create the class, those properties are already filled up by your default values:

```java
class MyObject
{
   int variableOne;
   int variableTwo;

   // Constructor
   public MyObject() {
     variableOne = 5;
     variableTwo = 10;
   }
}

// Create the instance of class
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(); // This automatically has the values 5 and 10 in variableOne and variableTwo
```

Also note some suggestions in the comments have static infront of fields that can be instantly initialized without a constructor. However, there can be an issue if there are multiple instances of the same class, all those static variables are shared amongst all the object. This is good only in very special scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Using one class, this shows various ways to initialize the values.

- The first is by default.  Just assign the values when the instance fields are declared.

```
MyClass mc1 = new MyClass();
System.out.println(mc1);
```

prints

```
10, 20, Java
```

- The most common method is to use a constructor by passing arguments to the class.

```
MyClass mc2 = new MyClass(100,200,"Java!!");
System.out.println(mc2);
```

prints

```
100, 200, Java!!
```

- Setters are used to assign different values as needed.

```
 
MyClass mc3 = new MyClass();
System.out.println("Before assignment: " + mc3); 
mc3.setVar1(1000);
mc3.setVar2(2000);
mc3.setVar3("Java!!");
System.out.println("After assignment:  " + mc3);
```

prints

```
Before assignment: 10, 20, Java
After assignment:  1000, 2000, Java!!
```

```
class MyClass {
    int var1 = 10;
    int var2 = 20;
    String var3 = "Java";
    public MyClass(int var1, int var2, String var3) {
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
        this.var3 = var3;
    }
    public MyClass() {
    }
    public void setVar1(int v) {
       this.var1 = v;
    }
    public void setVar2(int v) {
       this.var2 = v;
    }
    public void setVar3 (String v) {
       this.var3 = v;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return var1 + ", " + var2 + ", " + var3;
    }
}
```

For arrays lists one use `List.of()` which creates an immutable list.  If you want to create a mutable list, pass it as an argument to the `List` implementation constructor. This is demonstrated for maps as well.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Maps are similar but are limited to `10 key/value` pairs via(`k1, v1, k2, v2, etc`) when initializing this way.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1, "One", 2, "Two", 3, "Three", 4, "Four"));
```

or for any number of entries

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(Map.ofEntries(
         Map.entry(1,"One"),
         Map.entry(2,"Two),
         Map.entry(3,"Three"),
         Map.entry(4,"Four"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I've gained a lot from your answer! :)